# R bar chart data in rows

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am trying to make a graph in R with data like:

```
sex ethnicity x2015 x2016 x2017
-------------------------------

male    dutch      112    117   116   
female  dutch      114    118   120
female  german     102    101   99
etc
```

I want make a bart chart from each data row...

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, the aforementioned isn't a codewriting service, let us know what you've tried first. see: [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grouping Barplot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269695/grouping-barplot-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ggplot2` package using `stat = identity` and `facet_wrap`. Additionally you can use `melt` function from `reshape2` package to transform data convinient for use in `ggplot2` - from wide to narrow dataset format. Please see the code below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

data <- structure(list(sex = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("female", 
"male"), class = "factor"), ethnicity = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L
), .Label = c("dutch", "german"), class = "factor"), x2015 = c(112L, 
114L, 102L), x2016 = c(117L, 118L, 101L), x2017 = c(116L, 120L, 
99L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df <- melt(data)

ggplot(df, aes(x = ethnicity, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ sex)
```

Output:
[image]